# Cast void pointer to struct and move it given size

Tags: c, struct, void-pointers

I got a binary file that contains 3 different structs which I'm suppose to read to my program. After I have read the first struct I store its size, and then I'm suppose to convert my void pointer + the first structs length to a struct ip_hdr * (which is the second struct) and then read all it's values.

But the problems is I don't understand how you move a void pointer. I have understood that the void pointers don't have the same arithmetic rules as like a int pointer.

I want to do something like this:

```
ptr = (struct ip_hdr *)ptr) + (ethRes));
```

But that doesn't work instead I get following error message:

> Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Here is my code:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "framehdr.h"
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main()
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

    FILE *fileOpen = fopen("C:\\Users\\Viktor\\source\\repos\\Laboration_3\\Laboration_3\\TCPdump", "rb");


    //Pointers and variables
    struct ethernet_hdr eth;
    struct ethernet_hdr *ethPtr;
    struct ip_hdr ip;
    struct ip_hdr *ipPtr;
    struct tcp_hdr tcp;
    struct tcp_hdr *tcpPtr;

    if (fileOpen == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Success\n");
    }

    char ethrr[10];
    fscanf(fileOpen, "%s", ethrr);
    int length = atoi(ethrr);
    printf("Nr: %d\n", length);

    void *ptr;
    ptr = (void *)malloc(length);
    fread(ptr, sizeof(eth), 1, fileOpen);

    int ethRes = sizeof(((struct ethernet_hdr*)ptr)->dhost) +
        sizeof(((struct ethernet_hdr*)ptr)->shost) +
        sizeof(((struct ethernet_hdr*)ptr)->type);
    printf("%d\n", ethRes);
    printf("ptr1: %d\n", &ptr);

    system("pause");
    fclose(fileOpen);


    return 0;
}
```

I now it's broken but I'm not done with it. Just need help with the pointers for now.

Comment: Please don't describe your code but show it.

Comment: __But that doesn't work.__ Doesn't explains much! Also you are missing brackets `(` in `ptr = (struct ip_hdr *)ptr) + (sizeOfFirstStruct));` Please post your code.

Comment: @Gaurav how can I do it then? Should I cast the pointer first to the structure Ip_hdr and then move it or can I use some function like fseek to move it somehow?

Comment: Where is the `ptr = (struct ip_hdr *)ptr) + (sizeOfFirstStruct));` in the code you posted?

Comment: @MichaelWalz haven't it in the code since I get an error when I had it. "Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type" it said

Comment: @anderssinho OK, that should have been made clear in the question. Pleade [edit] your question and make that clear _there_

Comment: @4386427 yes and it does not chance the pointer :/

Comment: @MichaelWalz okay should I change the title to that error message or just add it in the text?

Comment: @MichaelWalz added the error message in the text. Thanks for helping me improve the question

Comment: `ptr = (struct ip_hdr *)ptr) + (sizeOfFirstStruct));` is wrong, please confirm that it is actually `ptr = ((struct ip_hdr *)ptr) + sizeOf(FirstStruct);`. Never retype code in question, but copy/paste it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161520/discussion-between-anderssinho-and-michael-walz).

Comment: @Yunnosch gives me the error "Expression must be a pointer to a complete object type" it said" and "Void* unknown size"

Answer (score 3):

This should work, assuming the structure is compatible with whatever is in the file (in general saving structs "raw" to disk is a bad idea, the exact layout of a struct in memory is compiler-dependent and not stable enough to use as a file format):

```
const struct ip_hdr * const ip = (struct ip_hdr *) ((struct ethernet_hdr *) ptr + 1);
```

This adds "1" to a pointer of type `ethernet_hdr`, which will advance the actual pointer value by whatever size the Ethernet header structure has. The result is then cast to `struct ip_hdr *`.

I think this is what you wanted to do. You can do it by adding bytes to a `char *`, but what's the point?

You can't add directly to the void pointer, since pointer arithmetic is always in units of whatever is pointed at, and `void` has no size.

Comment: I will try this immediately. The reason I want to do this is because I'm suppose to read the size of each struct and then access a textmessage that is located right after the last struct. So i'm suppose to work get size of a struct, cast my void pointer to next struct and increament it by the size of the previous struct until I reach the end.

Not sure if you understand what I'm trying to explain.

No I know that the arithmetic rules don't apply to a void type of pointer

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of moving along an array of structures using a pointer to `void`.

The compiler doesn't know the type of object pointed to by a `void*` pointer.
So you have two choices. One is to convert it to a pointer to the 'correct' type and then add the number of elements you want to move. The other is to add the number of bytes you want to an `unsigned char*` (or similar).

The action happens on the lines marked `[1]` and `[2]` below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int payload;
    double other;
} thingy;

int main(void) {
    thingy athingy[2];//An array of two thingys.
    void* voidptr=athingy; //a pointer to first thingy.

    thingy* nextthingy=((unsigned char*)voidptr)+sizeof(thingy); //[A] next thingy points to second element of array.
    thingy* altnext=((thingy*)voidptr)+1; //[B] Points to the same thing!

    printf("voidptr==%p %zu\n",voidptr,sizeof(thingy));
    printf("nextthingy==%p\n",nextthingy);
    printf("altthingy==%p\n",altnext);

    if(nextthingy==altnext){
        printf("Same\n");
    }else{
        printf("Not same (oh dear)\n"); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Typical output:

```
voidptr==0x7ffd6909d660 4
nextthingy==0x7ffd6909d664
altthingy==0x7ffd6909d664
Same
```

The actual values may vary.

**Caveat**

If I understand the question, the requirement is to move through a number of different `struct`s read together. 
That may be problematic because of alignment. It's beyond the scope of this question to go into detail but C may place or require padding between members or objects of different type to ensure they are aligned on the architecture. It's very common for example for 4 byte integers to lie on memory addresses that numerically divide by 4. That simplifies hardware and improves performance.

It's not clear from the fragment provided that the objects read in will be aligned and further copying of data and shuffling may be required.

That may have been taken into account but that can't be seen from the information provided.

What may help is the often overlooked `offsetof(,)` macro defined in `stddef.h`.

That returns the offset of a member within a type (taking internal padding into consideration). For example there is in general no guarantee (above) that:

```
voidptr+sizeof(payload)==((unsigned char*)voidptr)+offsetof(thingy,other)
```

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: My guess is you're probably compiling C++ not C as tagged. IMHO the fact that you can do pointer arithmetic on `void*` is an inconsistency of the type system in C tidied up in C++.

Comment: It does. It's a bad habit hole in GNU C I've dropped in.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie fixed.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer. But If i have 3 different structs in a binary file that are not in an array like your example. 
You point your void pointer to an array, and I just try to use fread to get the first struct in it.

How do I change my pointer from the first struct to the nexty struct? If I understand correct you only point to the next in the array of thingy: thingy* nextthingy=((unsigned char*)voidptr)+sizeof(thingy);

Or am I missunderstanding?

Comment: That's what I was musing about for alignment. If you read the first struct into `ptr` (your code) then advance is by `sizeof(ethernet_hdr)` bytes it might not be aligned to read the next structure in after it. You may be better reading all three in as separate reads into separate structs. You still need to know they'll be internally padded (or not) according to how your compiler has aligned the members or you end up reading member by member.

Comment: @anderssinho I should point out - that very much depends on the architecture you're building on and how portable you need to be. If you're reading from file in an environment where data may have been written on a different platform you may also have to contend with endianness too!